# Web API Parse URL parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, url-parameters, asp.net-web-api-routing

is there a way how to parse url parameters in this format:

```
products[0][id]=ABC123&products[0][count]=1&products[1][id]=ABC124&products[1][count]=2
```

into WebAPI method?

Comment: this kind of url is not recommended!! can u tell me what you want to achieve passing parameters like this? 
i can suggest you alternate ways!

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't affect URL format.

Comment: not advisable! can't u send as a json object??

Comment: I do not create the URL. URL in this format is sent to my API where I have to process it.

Comment: How come special characters are present in your URL?